# Linux kernel - Context switch when calling function from other module?

Tags: c, linux, module, operating-system, kernel

I am curious if calling a function from a different module in the Linux kernel triggers a context switch?

Basically, I'm doing something like this.

Say I have module A:

```
uint64_t time;
int core;
int foo(){
   time = rdtsc();
   core = smp_processor_id();
   return time;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL("foo");
```

module B:

```
uint64_t time1, time2;
int bar(){
    time1 = rdtsc();
    time2 = foo();
    printk(KERN_INFO "Difference: %d\n", time2-time1);
}
```

between the two measurements, I'm seeing a gap of up to 2 microseconds (after dividing through the TSC frequency). Could this gap be due to a context switch?

Comment: Can be whatever, the code execution time also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this does not trigger a context switch.

When loading a linux module, it is dynamically *linked* into the kernel, similar as how dynamic libraries (libc etc.) are linked in memory when starting a dynamically linked program. Therefore, the call to `foo()` is really just a *jump* instruction to the address of that function, which was resolved on module loading.

However, the linux kernel nowadays is *preemptive*, which means, that the execution of a process can be preempted even when it is currently in kernel space, so a context switch to another process is *possible*, but shouldn't be reproducible deterministically.

The time difference probably results from normal code execution, i.e. the calls to `rdtsc()` and `smp_processor_id()`.